# is there a way in preamble to modify/reduce the white space between letter followed by closed parenthesis ( and )?

Tags: spacing, typography, brackets

For me, I think Latex puts too much space between the function name and its arguments when using `\left(` and `\right)` compared to just `(` and `)`.  I'd like to get same space as with the second case.

The problem is that the Latex I am using is produced from CAS software which always generates `\left(` and `\right)` automatically. Sometimes this is what is actually needed and sometimes it is not needed.

So without changing the code itself, is there a way to make the space the same as when using `(` and `)` only? or reduce it somehow? May be with some smart macro or some package? I can only change the preamble, but do not want to edit anything after `\begin{document}` as the generated latex changes many times during the day or any time I re-run the CAS program.

Here is a comparison

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\[
Y \left(X \right) 
\]

\[
y \left(x \right) 
\]
\end{document}
```

vs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\[
Y (X) 
\]

\[
y (x) 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

All compiled using `lualatex foo.tex`.

We see the horizontal space between the function name, which is `Y` in this example and its arguments `()` is smaller when using `(` and `)` which is what I like more.

But it is not possible to modify the code generated each time. Both Maple and Mathematica always generate `\left( and \right)` even if what is inside the parenthesis is a single letter and not some complicated expression which would need `\left(` and `\right)` to adjust the height of the parenthesis to make its content fit right.  Also Scientific word which I use does the same, all its latex uses `\left( and \right)`.

TL 2021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set

```
\Umathordinnerspacing\textstyle=0mu
\Umathordinnerspacing\displaystyle=0mu
```

in luaTeX. But there is new problem when you are using Unicode Math: the italic correction after the Ord atom and the next Inner atom isn't included. The setting `\mathitalicsmode=1` does not help.

BTW: it is bug of your CAS software, you can try to report it.

Comment: One should be aware of that things like `\(a\cdots b\)` is affected by this, since `\cdots` results in an inner atom.